# Why is my HTTP Post not working in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, flask, post

I have my Flask application, with a `profile` function down below:

```
@app.route('/profile/')
def profile(username, password):
    return f"<h1>username entered: {username} password entered: {password}</h1>"
```

I also have my `login` function, that uses `login.html` as a template, and redirects to `profile` with the `username` and `password`.

Here is my login function:

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('login.html')
    elif request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        print(f'Username: {username}, Password: {password}')
        return redirect(url_for('profile', username=username, password=password))
```

Here is my `index.html` file (only the body part)

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, when I try to login and then submit, I get a TypeError, saying that my `profile` function is missing the two parameters. I got my username and password to print on the terminal, so I know that my login function is working well. Why does it have this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: @app.route('/profile/', methods=[ 'GET'] ) Try with this. I think the route got confused as method type is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in your profile function should correspond to url parameters. You will need to update the URL like so:

```
@app.route('/profile/<string:username>/<string:password>')
def profile(username, password):
    return f"<h1>username: {username} password entered: {password}</h1>
```

A more practical use of url parameters would be for example: fetching a user's profile given a user id

```
@app.route('/profile/<int:userId>', methods=["GET"])
def profile(userId):
    user = getUserById(userId) 
    return f"<h1>username: {user["username"]}. userId: {user["id"]}</h1>
```

Theoretically the request would look like the following: `GET /profile/20`
and the response: `<h1>username: foo. userId: 20</h1>`